# Objection-iOS issue

Tags: apportable

I have Objections-iOS as a 3rd party framework, recognised by XCode, but not by apportable.

In essence, `#import <Objection-iOS/Objection.h>` does not work so apportable chokes at this point.

I am aware of the header_path(s) property in the configuration, but try as I might, I still could not get apportable to load the headers from `$project_root/Frameworks/Objection-iOS.framework`

Have any of you had a similar problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to build that framework as a sub-project to get it to work the headers from the framework need to be re-organized to be in a directory called Objection-iOS to reference the correct paths. Unfortunately the linker does not support framework inclusions yet so we cannot build real frameworks as of current to add the -framework parameter to the compilation steps. On iOS and MacOSX this basically adds the Objection-iOS.framework/Headers into the include paths but remaps that part to be named Objection-iOS.

tl;dr;
Create a directory called Objection-iOS, add a header_paths entry that points to the container of that directory and it should pick up on the headers